# establishing mysql/java/jdbc connection in runtime eclipse applications

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, runtime, database-connection

i am making a swing based desktop application that is initiated through a menu command in a runtime  esclipe application.

- let me define the flow...

**aC** = main eclipse application project that contains all the coding for plugin development, it contains a sample menu command handler **newModule** and a swing application "App.java"

**Test** = test runtime Eclipse application.

when "aC" is run as "Eclipse Aplication", a new eclipse environment is loaded that contains the project "Test". Now when the command of "newModule" is run [Test->right click->newModule], "App.java" is initiated. [till here my application is working fine]

the next part of this whole plugin is there are a few options on each panel of "App.java" that need to be recorded in database. [this is where the problem lies]. when i try to run it as a standalone application [without the runtime part], the connection that i have established works fine but once the whole application is run [along with the runtime part] it gives me an error of **"classNotFoundException: jdbc:mysql:driver"**. it seems as if connection can not be established in eclipse runtime applications. is it so?

i took the following steps [in both plugin-project "aC" as well as runtime-eclipseApplication project "Test"] to resolve it but the problem was not solved.

- project->properties->java build path->libraries->add external jar->mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin

can anybody help me **"how to develop a connection between java and mysql using jdbc for runtime applications?"**

i m using wamp server and phpmyadmin as the backend database [if it helps]

Answer (score 0):

Generally you are asking how to connect to DB using plain JDBC.

Please take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-installing-classpath.html

This link explains how to install MySQL driver. Generally you just have to put the jar file somewhere into your classpath.

Then learn how to connect to jdbc: http://www.heimetli.ch/jdbc/JDBCQuery.html

Pay attention that first you have to initialize driver using `Class.forName(FULLY-QUALIFIED-DRIVER-NAME)` and then implement driver/db independent JDBC code.

Comment: no i m not asking that i know how to connect DB with plain jdbc and have done that. my problem states that when i run the connection statements on a standalone desktop a[[lication, it works fine. but when i try to use the same connection in a runtime eclipseApplication,  it shows a classnotfoundexception. i alsomentioned in my problem statement that i did put in the jar file  [as specified in tutorial] but i still can not make it work for a runtime application.

Comment: i solved my problem. i m posting it here so that anyone who is facing same problem can benefit from it too. 

follow these simple steps. 

1. add a folder **"lib"** to ur application

2. place "mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin" in lib

3. now open ur "MANIFEST.MF" and go to tab "RUNTIME"

4. on bottom right, u would c **"classpath"** ; click **"Add"**

5. now add the folder lib [created in step 1] along with the jar file 

in this way, whenever a runtime EclipseApplication /OSGi Application is started this jar file is exported along too. so the connectivity would then be available there too.